# Rails add index on year of created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, concurrency, activesupport

In my Rails app I have a model ticket. Its `created_at` field `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. It also has a `number` field of type integer. The `number` field is not the primary key. The primary key is a UUID.

In any year, I cannot have 2 tickets with the same number. For example, in year 2020 it is not allowed to have 2 tickets with number 15. However, it is allowed for 2 tickets to have the same number if they were created in different years. For example, a ticket created in 2019 has number 15 and a ticket created in 2020 has number 15 --- this is ok.

So I'm trying to add an index on tickets table on numbers and year of created_at and require the index to be unique:

```
class AddIndexToTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_index :tickets, "number,(created_at.year)", unique: true, name: 'index_tickets_uniqueness'
  end
end
```

This results in error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "created_at"
LINE 1: ..." ON "tickets"  (number,(created_at...
```

The reason for doing is to avoid concurrency issues. In my codes I have mechanisms for automatically increment `number` each time a new ticket is created. It works for most of the time. But it would become an issue if two tickets are being created very close to each other.

What should I do? Custom validation might also fail depending on exact timing, I think.

Thanks!

Comment: one more thing you could do aside from the answer you already have, is to let Postgres do the autoincrement part, don't do it with ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use Ruby syntax when you should be using PostgreSQL syntax. Calling `created_at.date` would work on a Ruby `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, but the argument you're passing to `add_index` is going to be evaluated by Postgres, not Ruby. So it's failing because, to Postgres, `created_at.date` is invalid syntax here. So to fix it you just need to switch to PostgreSQL syntax.

I think you could possibly achieve what you want with something like this:

```
add_index :tickets, "number, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)", unique: true, name: 'index_tickets_uniqueness_on_year'.
```

Untested, but it ought to work. [More info on the EXTRACT function and other Postgres Date/Time stuff here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html).